Лишний айди для связи с базовым классом в бд Entity Framework
У меня возникла проблема, что ef core создает лишний внешний ключ

вот таблица из бд, мне неизвестен ключ что за AuthorForMusicId
бд - postgres
код класса для автора музыки
public class AuthorForMusic : BaseUser
{ 
    public List<Music> CreatedMusics { get; set; } = [];
    public List<Album> Album { get; set; } = [];
}

базовый класс для автора
public abstract class BaseUser
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;


    public List<Music> Favourites { get; set; } = [];
    public List<Playlist> Playlists { get; set; } = [];

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

класс музыки
 public class Music
 {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
     public AuthorForMusic? Author { get; set; }
     public string Avatar { get; set; } = string.Empty;

     public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     public string Audio { get; set; } = string.Empty;

     public MusicCategories Category { get; set; }

     public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
     public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

     public List<Playlist> Playlist { get; set; } = [];
     public List<User> WhoFavorited { get; set; } = [];

     public Album? Album { get; set; }
     public Guid AlbumId { get; set; }
     
 }

конфигурация для автора
 public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AuthorForMusic> builder)
 {
    
     builder.HasBaseType<BaseUser>();
     builder.ToTable("BaseUser");


     builder
         .HasMany(x => x.CreatedMusics)
         .WithOne(p => p.Author)
         .HasForeignKey(x => x.AuthorId);

     builder
         .HasMany(a => a.Album)
         .WithOne(a => a.Author)
         .HasForeignKey(k => k.AuthorId);
    
 }

конфигурация для музыки
 public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Music> builder)
 {
     builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

     builder
         .HasMany(x => x.Playlist)
         .WithMany(p => p.MusicList);

     builder
         .HasMany(m => m.WhoFavorited)
         .WithMany(u => u.Favourites);


     builder
         .HasOne(x => x.Author)
         .WithMany(x => x.CreatedMusics)
         .HasForeignKey(x => x.AuthorId);

 }

вот что в консоли пишет ef core
CONSTRAINT "FK_Musics_BaseUser_AuthorForMusicId" FOREIGN KEY ("AuthorForMusicId")REFERENCES "BaseUser" ("Id"),

CONSTRAINT "FK_Musics_BaseUser_AuthorId" FOREIGN KEY ("AuthorId") REFERENCES "BaseUser" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE


Может при каком-то предыдущем прогоне создалось.
Чтобы проверить, либо зачистите текущую бд, либо создайте новую
и посмотрите появилась ли связь.
